# Jruby Applets: (LoadError) no such file to load

Tags: java, ruby, applet, jruby, nokogiri

I'm currently having real problems trying to get the gem Nokogiri to work in my applet. I have the jruby-complete-1.7.3 jar and have attempted to install gems using the normal install line:

```
java -jar jruby-compelete-1.7.3.jar -S gem install nokogiri
```

And also I have tried the Gem-In-A-Jar method. At first it works fine, and allows me to eval ruby code and store the data returned. My problem arises when I add in the line:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

While that line works fine in the irb, when trying to access it from the applet I get the following error:

```
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:396 warning: can't 
canonicalize loaded names due to security restrictions; disabling

Message: (LoadError) no such file to load -- nokogiri
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- nokogiri
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
at RUBY.require(classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
at RUBY.(root)(<script>:2)
```

I simply can't figure out why this exception is occuring. I've tried:

- moving the gems manually into the "META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared" folder
- I've added "require 'rubygems'" above the the nokogiri call.
- Accessing the gems via the Gems-in-a-jar method: http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar/

If anyone has an idea where I've gone wrong, or a solution to this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A tip.  Look at the numbers beside the tags on the RHS of the screen.  Applets 4000, JRuby 1600, nokogiri 1300.  Now hover over them and see how many people **follow** that topic.  I'll bet you'll find that the Java tag has about 500 times as many followers as applet (not to mention the other two).  So the tip is.. Don't forget to add the Java tag.  ;)

Comment: Yeah.. that is a significantly larger number of followers indeed.. Thanks for the tip Andrew!